# How to write regex to match number ranges?

Tags: regex

I am using the asp.net `RegularExpressionValidator` to check for input on a multiline textbox.  I ALMOST have it, but I must be missing something.  This is how it SHOULD be:

```
1 => valid

1-10 => valid

1-10,45,50 => valid

1 10 45 50 => valid

111 => INVALID
```

However, `111` is coming back Valid

Here is the regex I am using: `"(([0-9]{1,2})(,|\s|-)?)*"` and it works for everything but `111`, where it is saying valid.  I know why it thinks it's valid, I just don't know how to make that invalid.

Comment: what are you trying to validate? 3 digit numbers or just '111'?

Comment: The rule is they can type a number, or a number with a dash or a space,or both, but not more than one dash or space, and no letters and no numbers longer than 2 digits.

Comment: Now that I know what RegularExpressionValidator is, I kinda recommend you don't use it. Its a puff for what your doing. Whats your error message: "type a number, or a number with a dash or a space,or both, but not more than one dash or space, and no letters and no numbers longer than 2 digits" ?? Better to go with a custom onkeydown event handler type thing to ALLOW only the right keypress, instead of some bizzaro invalid input message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the seperator optional, then you will match number-nothing-number, and therefore match 111, instead do something like:

```
"[0-9]{1,2}([-,\s][0-9]{1,2})*"
```

**edit:** for clarity: If your regex engine does not match the whole string, you need to add `^` at the start, and `$` at the end of the regex.

Comment: realy? according to [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) it will also match 111. I think there are anchors `\b` needed, see my answer below.

Comment: @stema, this is a good answer, it only matches because he's missing begining and end anchors, if added `/^([0-9]{1,2}([-,\s][0-9]{1,2})*)$/` should work fine.

Comment: As I understand it, anchors aren't needed in RgularExpressionValidator regexes because the matches are implicitly anchored at both ends.  But you do have to add a RequiredFieldValidator if you don't want to accept empty strings.

Comment: @Alan Moore - RegularExpressionValidator is new to me until today. Imagine that! Microsoft requires the entire field, every character to be regex validated. Why? Because they know developers are ignorant of regex, and they want to protect global form submission, as if it will protect them, and there is no such thing as `[\S\s]+`. An amazing display of paternal big brother. Should I wish to validate an existence of 'foo' in a field, 'foo' is not valid. Constructs like (?=a|$) might screw up in the presence of full field descriptions. And what if I want to validate per onkeydown...

Answer (score 0):

Your regex as written is matching "11" from "111" and zero occurrences of the repeating pattern.  If you wrap your regex in ^...$ it should work:

```
^(([0-9]{1,2})(,[\s-])?)*$
```

Since then the regex will not permit any additional characters in the string.

Comment: Nope, that will still match 111, since it's the nullable seperator which makes it possible to match 111.

Answer (score 0):

After your `[0-9]{1,2}` term, you need a negative lookahead to ensure that the next character isn't a digit as well.  I'm not familiar with asp.net, but something like `[0-9]{1,2}(?![0-9])` might yield better results.  See [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more information about lookahead.

**Edit:** The regex posted above helps, but still matches the last two digits of `111`.  The following regex should work (as verified using an [online regex tester](http://regexpal.com/)).  It adds a word-boundary anchor at the beginning, which should prevent the expression from starting a match in the middle of a number.  It also makes the delimiter mandatory instead of optional.  This combination removes the need for the lookahead.

```
(\b([0-9]{1,2})(-|,|\s|$))+
```

Comment: @sln- The regular expression tester that I was using is powered by Javascript's regex engine and I suppose that the asp.net engine is designed a bit differently.

Comment: `(whatever)*` will always report a successful match because it can match an empty string wherever it's applied.  That's true of every regex flavor I know of.

Comment: @Alan Moore- Good catch, that `*` should be a `+` instead.  I'll fix the typo in my answer.  Thanks

Comment: I'm new to RegularExpressionValidator, but now I know what it is. The apparent fact is that /^..$/ is implied, meaning /^(anything)*$/ will possibly ONLY match the empty string, which is cured by setting another flag in that validation class. ()+ cures both problems, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Left-anchor your pattern with `^`. The `*` is greedy and you're matching on the second and third `1` in `111`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to make things a bit simpler, break it up into multiple regex checks?

If string matches `(([0-9]{1,2})(,|\s|-)?)*`, then check if string matches `\d{3,}`. If it does, then fail else pass.

Comment: `(([0-9]{1,2})(,|\s|-)?)*` matches everything

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to require the delimiter. '?' allows zero or one instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two issues. One issue is a regex that validates on each character a user enters. Another regex to extract the data afterwards.

To use a regex that validates upon each enterred character, the end anchor is more important than the beginning, although the beginning anchor, unwanted characters can get in.

So on rubular.com, this particular regex allows for [, -] characters using the rules

1. no more than 2 digits in a row
2. commma or space or dash, not more than 2 in a row

In the end, data extraction will be different, so this just works on a user entered per-character basis.

It worked on everything I tried as far as variants.

`^(?:\b\d{1,2}(?:([, -])(?!\1)[, -]?|))+$`

The `\b` is indeed necessary to distinquish 3 digits in a row.
Try it out.